# Python Beautiful Soup how to JSON decode to `dict`?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to BeautifulSoup in Python and I'm trying to extract `dict` from BeautifulSoup.

I've used BeautifulSoup to extract JSON and got `beautifulsoup.beautifulsoup` variable `soup`.

I'm trying to get values out of `soup`, but when I do `result = soup.findAll("bill")` I get an empty list `[]`. How can I extract soup to get `dict` result of:

```
{u'congress': 113,
 u'number': 325,
 u'title': u'A bill to ensure the complete and timely payment of the obligations of the United States Government until May 19, 2013, and for other purposes.',
 u'type': u'hr'}


print type(soup)
print soup
```

=> result below

```
BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup

{
  "bill": {
    "congress": 113, 
    "number": 325, 
    "title": "A bill to ensure the complete and timely payment of the obligations of the United States Government until May 19, 2013, and for other purposes.", 
    "type": "hr"
  }, 
  "category": "passage", 
  "chamber": "s"
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is how I got `soup`:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2 
url = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.govtrack.us/data/congress/113/votes/2013/s11/data.json")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` is used to work with html/xml. Where does json data come from? Is it embed in html? If so, please, provide the corresponding html fragment.

Comment: Why are you using BeautifulSoup? It looks like all you need is `json_decode`...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not very familiar with BeautifulSoup but if you just need to decode JSON

```
import json

newDictionary=json.loads(str(soup))
```

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: I was getting `No JSON object` because Beautifulsoup was returning a whole script tag so I just needed to do `newDictionary=json.loads(str(soup.text))`

Answer (score 17):

You could remove `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import json
import urllib2

url = "https://www.govtrack.us/data/congress/113/votes/2013/s11/data.json"
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
```